# How to show product sizes related to product using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show product sizes related to product I already have made a relation b/w tables into database i just only want to know that when i click the specific product the size related to that product will be shown in the table.inside function how to make joining b/w three tables please make the join table using DB class because it will be easy to understand for me  thanks.

Does Anyone have an idea ?

```
  please check product sizes image 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt6Jk.png
```

**Database**

```
    product_sizes  table
   ----------------------------------------------------
   id   |  size_name  | Body_length  |  Body_width | 
   ----------------------------------------------------
    1    |    M        |     2.3       |      3.4
    2    |    L        |     .5        |      4.4
    3    |    s        |     2.5       |      3.2
    4    |    xs       |     3.5       |      2.4


   products table
  ----------------------------------------
   id   |  product_name | Description |  
  ----------------------------------------
   1     Ultraclub 1   | Ultraclub 300 |
   2     Ultraclub 2   | Ultraclub 200 |
   3     Ultraclub 3   | Ultraclub 500 |
   4     Ultraclub 4   | Ultraclub 600 |
   5     Ultraclub 5   | Ultraclub 400 |



  available_product_sizes table
  ----------------------------------------
   id   |  product_id  | product_size_id  
  ----------------------------------------
   1     | 2           |  1
   2     | 3           |  4
   3     | 4           |  3
   4     | 1           |  2
   5     | 2           |  3
```

**Controller**

```
         public function single_product($product_slug){

         $Sizes=DB::table('product_sizes')->get();    

         $single_product=DB::table('products')->where('product_slug',$product_slug)->get();

         return view('front_end/single_product',compact('single_product','Sizes'));
        }
```

**html view**

```
             <div class="product-tabs__pane product-tabs__pane--active" id="chart">
              <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
              <tr style="background-color:#3366cc;color:white">
              <td><b>Sizes</b>
              </td>
              <td><b>Body length</b>
              </td>
              <td><b>Body width</b>
              </td>
              <td><b>Sleeve length</b>
              </td>
              </tr>
              @foreach($Sizes as  $size)
              <tr>
            <td><b>{{$size->sizes_name}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>{{$size->Body_length}}</td>
            <td>{{$size->Body_width}}</td>
            <td>{{$size->Sleeve_length}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: I understand that you might find DB easier to understand but eloquent in Laravel is way better than using DB in relations, It's like someone that doesn't upgrade his php from 7 to 7.4 because he is afraid things will break and knows it better. But in the end it is better to upgrade and learn new things. Eloquent is definitely highly recommended. Also easier once you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're already has/desfined [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `products` and `product_sizes` tables

```
//App\Product.php

public function sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductSize', 'available_product_sizes', 'product_id', 'product_size_id');
}

//App\ProductSize.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'available_product_sizes', 'product_size_id', 'product_id');
}
```

In order to get available product sizes you can use :

```
$sizes = App\Product::find(1)->sizes()->orderBy('size_name')->get();
```

Controller fix

```
public function single_product($product_slug) {

    $single_product = Product::with('sizes')->where('product_slug',$product_slug)->first();

    return view('front_end/single_product',compact('single_product'));
}
```

View Fix

```
//...
@foreach($single_product->sizes as  $size)
        <tr>
            <td>
               <b>{{$size->sizes_name}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>{{$size->Body_length}}</td>
            <td>{{$size->Body_width}}</td>
            <td>{{$size->Sleeve_length}}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
//...
```

Comment: I have used your code but i am facing error how to fix it

https://flareapp.io/share/17WVRGPX?owner_token=P5HjGlu5teXgln31BIPkcLHF5shs9dzU#F48

Comment: Oh you mistaken here @foreach($single_product as $single_products)
$single_product is like refers to "One single product" you don't need to loop through it. instead make use of {{$single_product->product_image}}

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question without using eloquent

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //include this
$products = DB::table('products as p')
     ->join('available_product_sizes as aps','aps.product_id','p.id')
     ->join('product_sizes ps','ps.id','aps.product_size_id')
     ->where('product_slug',$product_slug)->get();
```

But it is highly recommended to use eloquent relationships.